# Netbeans Database Explorer and Microsoft SQL Server not getting along

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, netbeans-7

I am trying to get a Java desktop application to pull some data from a Microsoft SQL-Server 2008 Database.   Netbeans database explorer can generate Entity classes from database tables, but I was unable to get this feature working. Normally, when you conect to a database, you see something like this:[image: Netbeans Database Explorer View]

I entered the database URL, username and password, and the connection was established.  But when I tried to explore the tables, they were all empty.  Instead of the nice tree above, I was just given a list of empty Schemas.  Mutlitple user names were tried, all had the same issue.  Since there was no schema on the database matching the username, a number of different schemas were displayed for me to choose.  Regardless of which one I chose, when I expanded it nothing showed up inside the Table, or the Views.

To verify that the useranema and password did have access to the tables I am interested in, I wrote a short Java method to connect to the database and display the ResultSet for a query. It worked as expected.  Why was the netbeans database explorer unable to find the tables?

I was hoping to use this tool to generate Entity classes with Netbeans, but apparently Microsoft SQL erver won't have it. I am using netbeans 7.1; documentation for the database explorer tool is found [on db.netbeans.org](http://db.netbeans.org/doc/howtostart.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I had the same problem with JDBC driver from Microsoft. I tried another one, the project jTDS (available on SourceForge). It could solve my problem. Some forums recommend always to use this driver because it is much faster.

Comment: Were you able to explore the database and generate entity classes?

Comment: Yes, I was able to explore the database, but I didn't try to generate entity classes. I suppose Microsoft JDBC driver's database metadata methods were not implemented, that's why normal queries work fine, but there are problems with DB exploration.